# Drupal 7 site migration to different domain

Tags: drupal-7, migration

I migrated my Druapl 7 site from a domain: **fourth.third.second.first/subfolder** to a different domain and the new adress is only **third.second.first** itself, without any subfolder. The home page loads without any problems. When I type in the default option (in the URL adress bar of the web browser) for logging in for users "**third.second.first/user**" it doesnt work either. What can be causing this problem?

I already checked .htaccess RewriteBase settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you check settings.php?
there is a base_url setting there which lets you set the base url.

Comment: you can try going into the database and empty all the cache_[name] tables.

Comment: thank you for all the help, actually the problem was in the clean URL settings. .htaccess clean URL option modification resolves the issue.

Comment: What modification did you do for the clean URL settings? I am stuck with the similar problem and not able to resolve it.